# (Proof verification) Openness and closedness of subsets of Rn

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I wanted to see weather these proofs are correct:

> 1) $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $a \in A \Rightarrow A \setminus \{a\}$ is open.

Proof: $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open $\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$ is closed $\Rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n \cup \{a\}) \setminus A$ is closed $\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \setminus (A \setminus \{a\})$ is closed $\Rightarrow  A \setminus \{a\} $ is open.

> 2) $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is closed and $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open $\Rightarrow F \setminus A$ is closed

Proof: $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is closed $\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$ is open $\Rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n \cup A) \setminus F$ is open $\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \setminus (F \setminus A)$ is open $\Rightarrow F \setminus A$ is closed.

Comment: Don't you mean $a\in A$ (or equivalently $\{a\}\subseteq A$)? Secondly $\mathbb R^n\cup B=\mathbb R^n$ for every $B\subseteq\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}^n \cup B = \mathbb{R}^n$ for every $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed in the proof.

Comment: But then e.g. $(\mathbb R^n\cup A)\setminus F=\mathbb R^n\setminus F$ and not (as you seem to claim) $\cdots=\mathbb R^n\setminus(F\setminus A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs are not correct. From e.g. the openess of $(\mathbb R^n\cup A)\setminus F=\mathbb R^n\setminus F$  you cannot just conclude openess of $\mathbb R^n\setminus(F\setminus A)$.

---

I preassume that $\mathbb R^n$ is equipped with its usual topology.

---

1) Singletons are closed so $\{a\}^c:=\mathbb R^n\setminus\{a\}$ is open.

Consequently $A\setminus\{a\}=A\cap\{a\}^c$ is (as the intersection of two open sets) open.

2) Here $F$ and $A^c$ are closed.

Consequently $F\setminus A=F\cap A^c$ is (as intersection of two closed sets) closed.